# Phonegap: Is local storage still limited to 5mb?

Tags: cordova

Is there still a limit of 5mb on localstorage?
I'm getting conflicting answers when I search on Google.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a [table](http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/) with all android and blackberry based browsers localStorage limit, you can test it from your device.

Answer (score 0):

**Local Storage size limit:**
Web storage provides far greater storage capacity (5 MB per origin in Google Chrome,Mozilla Firefox,and Opera; 10 MB per storage area in Internet Explorer;25MB per origin on BlackBerry 10 devices) compared to 4 kB (around 1000 times less space) available to cookies. ( source [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage))